# How to transform an item into a key/value pair object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, list, arraylist

I have a problem converting my data structure to a Key/Value Item.

I already tried some mapping and transformation, but my desired output is not shown on my console.

I have this code output of my function:

**Console:** `{BLAU: Array(1), ROT: Array(2)}`

and opened:

**Console:**

```
- BLAU: [{…}]
- ROT: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

---

```
const vorher = [{
    BLAU: [{
      type: 'mytype1'
    }],
  },
  {
    ROT: [{
      type: 'mytype1'
    }],
    [{
      type: 'mytype2'
    }]
  }
];
```

My desired output should be something like this:

```
const nachher = [{
    farbe: 'BLAU',
    typen: [{
      type: 'mytype1'
    }]
  },
  {
    farbe: 'ROT',
    typen: [{
      type: 'mytype1'
    }],
    [{
      type: 'mytype2'
    }]
  },
];
```

**EDIT:**

I have something like this as output from a function [{…}, {…}, {…}], it looks like this:

`[
     {
       id: 100,
       system: {id: 101, label: "BLAU", createdAt: "2019-07-30"},
       details: [{...},{...}],
       info: "Test"
     },
     {
       id: 400,
       system: {id: 404, label: "ROT", createdAt: "2019-07-30"},
       details: [{...},{...}],
       info: "Test"
     }
   ]`

I want to group this one by **system label** with the desired output above. GroupBy only gives me an Object back.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: `ROT` is not a correct object. Correct your question first.

Comment: @AdamOrlov sry, yeah the example was not correct, better now?

Comment: do you have only a single property in the outer objects?

Comment: Why not `typen: [{
      type: 'mytype1'
    },
    {
      type: 'mytype2'
    }]` or shorter: `typen: ['mytype1','mytype2']`

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah the outer one is **groupBy** the "farbe" attribute, only one "farbe" and a set of "typen"

Comment: @mplungjan because its not only type, its id and other informations. simplified the example

Comment: @Maverick777 still not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the first entry of the object, destructure it to the wanted key/value pair and retund a new object.

```js
const
    data = [{ BLAU: [{ type: 'mytype1' }] }, { ROT: [{ type: 'mytype1' }, { type: 'mytype2' }] }],
    result = data.map(o => {
        var [farbe, typen] = Object.entries(o)[0];
        return { farbe, typen };
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: And what if i have only this input:

{ BLAU: [{ type: 'mytype1' }] }, { ROT: [{ type: 'mytype1' }, { type: 'mytype2' }] } and not [{ BLAU: [{ type: 'mytype1' }] }, { ROT: [{ type: 'mytype1' }, { type: 'mytype2' }] }] ?

or can i easily convert the first one above to the item (data) shown in your answer ?

Comment: you can not have this. just more objects without a container like an array.

Comment: Ah okay i found the mistake i guess. My Output of the GroupBy ist not the same as i described above. my output is { BLAU: [{ type: 'mytype1' }] }, { ROT: [{ type: 'mytype1' }, { type: 'mytype2' }] }

Comment: it misses still the array around.

Comment: unfortunately my groupBy (ramda) function only gives me this output. It is an object as return type, not an array. You habe an idea what i can do about it ?

Comment: please add the whole object to the question.

Comment: i added my output above to my question

Comment: please add the output as well.